# What is the difference between masterslave discovery and static discovery in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, high-availability, failover, master-slave, discovery

> A common configuration option for a network of brokers is to establish a network bridge between a broker and an n+1 broker pair (master/slave). Typical configurations involve using the `failover:` transport, but there are a some other non-intuitive options that must be configured for it to work as desired. For this reason, ActiveMQ v5.6+ has a convenience discovery agent that can be specified with the `masterslave:` transport prefix:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*static:* discovery creates a network bridge for every uri in the list.

*masterslave:* creates one bridge and fails over to the other uri(s) in the list during an outage.